# Can You Use A DynamicResource in a Storyboard Contained Within Style Or ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, animation

I am trying to use a DynamicResource in Storyboard contained within a ControlTemplate.

But, when I try to do this, I get a 'Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads' error.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, you can't use a DynamicResource in a Storyboard that is contained within a Style or ControlTemplate. In fact, you can't use a data binding expression either.

The story here is that everything within a Style or ControlTemplate must be safe for use across threads and the timing system actually tries to freeze the Style or ControlTemplate to make them thread-safe. However, if a DynamicResource or data binding expression is present, it is unable to freeze them.

For more info see: [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx). Check out the 'Animate in a Style' and the 'Animate in a ControlTemplate' sections (this documentation page is rather long).

And for a workaround (at least for my scenario) see: [WPF Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9336022f-badb-4b40-a86c-a50ab1a64ba5/).

Hope this helps someone. I've lost more than enough hair on it.

Cory

Comment: Wow, this sucks really much, but thanks for at least explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

In some scenarios, there is a workaround:

- introduce an attached property,
- specify a style trigger for that introduced property with desired setter(s)

Answer (score 0):

While you can have `DynamicResource` in a `ControlTemplate`, you just can't have one in a `StoryBoard`.

I worked around this with a `Opacity` (or `Visibility`) hack.
You can add two elements to your `ControlTemplate`. Each of them uses one of the  `DynamicResources` but only one of them is visible. You can set the `Visibility` or `Opacity` of each element via the `Storyboard`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use sb in code

```
    public static void ColorAnimation(FrameworkElement Obj,  string From, string To, int Milliseconds)
    {
        Color from = ( Color )ColorConverter.ConvertFromString( From );
        Color to = ( Color )ColorConverter.ConvertFromString( To );
        {
            ColorAnimation animation = new ColorAnimation();
            animation.From = from;
            animation.To = to;
            animation.Duration = new Duration( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( Milliseconds ) );
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty( animation, new PropertyPath( "(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)", null ) );
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add( animation );
            storyboard.Begin( Obj );
        }
    }
```

Use in mouse_leave event: (or also in mouse_enter)

if( your theme determinant 1 ) ColorAnimation( MinimizeButton, "#FF333333", "#00202020", 150 );
if( your theme determinant 2 ) ColorAnimation( MinimizeButton, "#FF32506E", "#0032506E", 200 );

etc...