# 'Fill' property does not point to a dependencyobject in path '(0).(1)'

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I have a control template (which is the header component of a DevExpress `NavBarGroup` - in order to change the expand/collapse icon DevExpress requires to override the whole control template) with a button inside, which also has its own control template, which then contains a content control pointing to another control template with paths inside. Kinda like this in pseudo-Xaml:

```
<NavBarGroupHeader>
  <ExplorerBarExpandButton>
    <Path>
      <SolidColorBrush/>
    </Path>
  </ExplorerBarExpandButton>
</NavBarGroupHeader>
```

Now, there are various things happening. The outer most template of the `NavBarGroupHeader` contains the problematic animation logic: As soon as the header gets hovered the `Path`'s fill color is supposed to change. There are actually two buttons inside depending on the state of the `NavBarGroupHeader` using the same logic and looks, which is why I outsourced it into a template. The `NavBarGroupHeader` can be used with an `ExplorerBarView` or a `NavPaneView`, which then activates either of the buttons inside (the `ExplorerBarExpandButton` is used in this case and the `NavPaneExpandButton` gets ignored - but it's still there and viable).

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dxn:NavBarGroupHeader}>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinition>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
          <Storyboard>
            <!-- these two lines throw the exception -->
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=ArrowTop}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0" To="#201F35"/>
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=ArrowBottom}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0" To="#201F35"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroup>

    <!-- This shows a text within the header -->
    <dxn:ImageAndTextContentPresenter/>

    <dxn:ExplorerBarExpandButton x:Name="ExplorerBarExpandButton"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Template="{StaticResource GroupBoxExpandButtonTemplate}"/>

    <dxn:NavPaneExpandButton x:Name="NavPaneExpandButton"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Template="{StaticResource GroupBoxExpandButtonTemplate}"/>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `ExplorerBarExpandButton` contains two icons, looking the same, but one is flipped upside down with a `LayoutTransform`, which is why I outsorced the path into its own template. It also contains the logic of showing and hiding either of the buttons depending on whether the `NavBarGroup` is expanded or collapsed, which changes if you click the header (this is predetermined by DevExpress and works fine).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GroupBoxExpandButtonTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
      </VisualStateGroup>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Expanded"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
          <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphClose" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Visibility)" dxcn:ValueSetter.Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphOpen" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Visibility)" dxcn:ValueSetter.Visibility="Visible"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <ContentControl x:Name="GlyphClose"
                    Template="{StaticResource CollapseExpandIconTemplate}"/>
    <ContentControl x:Name="GlyphOpen"
                    Template="{StaticResource CollapseExpandIconTemplate}">
      <ContentControl.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
      </ContentControl.LayoutTransform>
    </ContentControl>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The path is actually a `StackPanel` with two `Paths` inside (two arrows pointing in the same direction). Therefore I actually wanted to use a `DynamicResource` of a color but after hours of trying and searching I stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154206/can-you-use-a-dynamicresource-in-a-storyboard-contained-within-style-or-controlt) explaining that it is not possible to access a resource inside the targeted element from within a storyboard. So, now I'm left with this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CollapseExpandIconTemplate">
  <StackPanel>
    <Path x:Name="ArrowTop" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#80838F" Data="M 0,50 25,50 50,30 75,50 100,50 100,40 50,0 0,40 Z"/>
    <Path x:Name="ArrowBottom" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#80838F" Data="M 0,50 25,50 50,30 75,50 100,50 100,40 50,0 0,40 Z"/>
  </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In multiple other posts (actually in everyone concerning this error) I've read that the declaration of a `SolidColorBrush` in the path is missing but adding it doesn't change anything. I still get the same error with this:

```
</Path ...>
  <Path.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#80838F"/>
  </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

I also tried using dynamic resources everywhere but it showed the same exception. I tried using `DoubleAnimation` for the different color parts but that throws another exception (with and without brackets around the R):

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(0).(1).(R)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

I tried to change the path because I wasn't sure whether it was actually correct but nothing worked.

Now I'm out of ideas. How can I get this storyboard to work?

**EDIT:**

I've tried another thing, reducing the Xaml to the simplest basics, eliminating all duplicate elements and merging all the templates together without using any resources, changing background color from the outermost element and then step by step to the innermost until I've reached the path's template, then moving the templates back into resources.

This is the Xaml outcome:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dxn:NavBarGroupHeader}>
  <Grid x:Name="HeaderRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinition>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
          <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=HeaderRoot}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0" To="#201F35"/>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroup>

    <!-- This shows a text within the header -->
    <dxn:ImageAndTextContentPresenter/>

    <dxn:ExplorerBarExpandButton x:Name="ExplorerBarExpandButton"
                                 Grid.Column="1">
      <dxn:ExplorerBarExpandButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="GroupBoxExpandButtonTemplate">
          <Grid x:Name="ExpandButtonRoot">
            <Grid.Background>
              <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
            </Grid.Background>

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              </VisualStateGroup>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Expanded"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphClose" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Visibility)" dxcn:ValueSetter.Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphOpen" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Visibility)" dxcn:ValueSetter.Visibility="Visible"/>
                  </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <ContentControl x:Name="GlyphClose">
              <ContentControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                  <StackPanel x:Name="PathRoot">
                    <Path x:Name="ArrowBottom" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#80838F" Data="M 0,50 25,50 50,30 75,50 100,50 100,40 50,0 0,40 Z"/>
                  </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </ContentControl.Template>
            </ContentControl>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </dxn:ExplorerBarExpandButton.Template>
    </dxn:ExplorerBarExpandButton>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In this case there is no exception thrown and the first part worked fine. The whole header background changes when I hover over it. Then I've changed the line to:

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=ExpandButtonRoot}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Duration="0" To="#201F35"/>
```

And oddly enough, still the whole header background gets changed upon hovering over it instead of just the button's background. I don't know what's going on here.